# why rotation speed increases as i create new sphere using webgl at same position

Tags: javascript, webgl

There is something strange going on, i  am drawing a sphere dynamically using lesson11 of github.com on link http://learningwebgl.com/blog/?p=1253 , 
By dynamically mean i am taking  latitudeBands and longitudeBands from the user at run time and he may change them run time to form a new sphere. (User has a choice to select at run time the  latitudeBands and longitudeBands values from the given UI item option in html)

I am creating sphere using those  latitudeBands and longitudeBands using the same concepts as on this link and it works fine and which i auto rotate by doing like this:

```
//rotation is at the end of the loop method 'tick'
function tick() {

    requestAnimFrame(tick);

    gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.viewportWidth, gl.viewportHeight);
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    mat4.perspective(45, gl.viewportWidth / gl.viewportHeight, 0.1, 100.0, pMatrix);

    gl.uniform1i(shaderProgram.useLightingUniform, false);

    mat4.identity(mvMatrix);
    mat4.translate(mvMatrix, [0, 0, -6]);
    mat4.multiply(mvMatrix, RotationMatrix);

    gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0);
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, imageTexture);

    gl.uniform1i(shaderProgram.samplerUniform, 0);

    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, VertexPositionBuffer);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(shaderProgram.vertexPositionAttribute, VertexPositionBuffer.itemSize, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, VertexTextureCoordBuffer);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(shaderProgram.textureCoordAttribute, VertexTextureCoordBuffer.itemSize, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, VertexNormalBuffer);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(shaderProgram.vertexNormalAttribute, VertexNormalBuffer.itemSize, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, VertexIndexBuffer);

    setMatrixUniforms();

    /*Rotation code is below*/
    var newRotationMatrix = mat4.create();
    mat4.identity(newRotationMatrix);
    mat4.rotate(newRotationMatrix, degToRad(5 / 10), [0, 1, 0]);
    mat4.multiply(newRotationMatrix, RotationMatrix, RotationMatrix);

    gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, VertexIndexBuffer.numItems, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);

}
```

**Where is the problem ?**

The problem is for the first time when i select the value dynamically it works fine.  But when i select another(on second time or more) value for latitudeBands and longitudeBands at runtime from UI then the rotation speed becomes faster then previous rotation of sphere
and speed of rotation keeps on increasing as i select again  and again dynamic latitudeBands and longitudeBands values.

Why this strange behavior, why it increases the speed of rotation for newly formed sphere by  selected latitudeBands and longitudeBands, The rotation speed is supposed to be same  as i re-draw a new sphere with new latitudeBands and longitudeBands values at same position?
  How to avoid it ?

**EDIT1:**

```
var RotationMatrix = mat4.create();
mat4.identity(RotationMatrix);
```

and setMatrixUniforms() is

```
function setMatrixUniforms()
    {
        gl.uniformMatrix4fv(shaderProgram.pMatrixUniform, false, pMatrix);
        gl.uniformMatrix4fv(shaderProgram.mvMatrixUniform, false, mvMatrix);
        var normalMatrix = mat3.create();
        mat4.toInverseMat3(mvMatrix, normalMatrix);
        mat4.transpose(normalMatrix);
        gl.uniformMatrix3fv(shaderProgram.nMatrixUniform, false, normalMatrix);
    }
```

**Could it be the reason that some matrice is not refreshed, or the rotation keeps on increasing with previous value?**

Comment: how is `RotationMatrix` defined ?

Comment: @Atrahasis please see the edit1 in the question.

Comment: ok. And where do you send `newRotationMatrix` to the shader ? In `setMatrixUniforms()` at next frame ? Just asking... for your main question I do not seem to have an idea.

Comment: please see the edit1 again. thats whar i have in setuniform function, but i do not have newRotationMatrix anywhere else in my code except in tick(); , Could that be mistake ?

Comment: Can you show the callback that handles the user's update of latitudeBands and longitudeBands?

Answer (score 0):

I think `mat4.multiply(newRotationMatrix, RotationMatrix, RotationMatrix);` should be `mat4.multiply(newRotationMatrix, RotationMatrix, newRotationMatrix);` ?